# Should questions that ask about using “web shops” be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, public-beta

There are some questions about Amazon ordering system etc. See:

- [Is there a way to make Amazon visually show me that a product can’t be shipped to my default location?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/is-there-a-way-to-make-amazon-visually-show-me-that-a-product-cant-be-shipped-to)
- [How do I remove 1 item from an Amazon order?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/how-do-i-remove-1-item-from-an-amazon-order)

  Given that there are a 101 web shops, do we wish this site to become a support site for everyone that is not happy with a shopping site?

Answer (score 6):

This is not different from the following questions where someone asks about not being able to do something on [Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/automatic-untagging-in-facebook-photos-uploaded-by-a-specific-person), or [Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/wildcard-search-in-gmail), or a more obscure app like [Fitbit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/web-app-fitbit-is-there-anyway-to-add-a-column-to-the-food-tracker-to-show-ww-po) (that I haven't heard of personally)?

Comment: This answer is actually another question, one of clarifying the originally posted question.  Would it be correct to assume that the *implied* answer to the original question is "yes"?